# aspmvc - Script bundle on debug how to force reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

I have a `ASP.NET MVC5` application and I have the following bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appcomponents").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/modernizr.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/detect.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/fastclick.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.slimscroll.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.blockUI.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/waves.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/wow.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.nicescroll.js",
                       "~/Scripts/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"));
```

When I'm in `DEBUG` mode I would like the browser to reload the scripts, actually I don't know if this already happens. If I set:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Then it works because I only get one dynamic reference, but in Developement (`DEGUB`) I don't get the dynamic parameter:

[image]

I was trying to do something like this but It didnt work:

[image]

> Any clue? Or by default when you have bundle it doesn't matter if you are in `DEBUG` mode you always get the latest script?

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding, you want to always get the newest scripts when in development (so no bundling and minification)

when you say debug, make sure your `web.config` should have compilation to `debug="true"`, like below:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <!-- Lines removed for clarity. -->
</system.web>
```

then bundling and minification should be turn off

if you set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`, that means even when `<compilation debug="true" />`, bundling and minification **will still function**.

so you problem probably is because you are setting `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` which means you have activated bundling and minification all the time even in debug hence may be not getting the newest script

if bundling and minification is turn off but you still not seeing the newest script, it maybe browser is caching it, try load it in chrome `incognito mode`

more info about controlling bundling and minification, checkout official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#controlling-bundling-and-minification

Comment: In my case, this is a caching issue in Chrome. Refreshing with `shift+F5` to ignore cache solved the issue.